# How to handle input from a textbox to not print a NaN

Tags: javascript, alert, nan

I am trying to get user input from the textbox and then click the button beside in order to calculate the area of a circle. Problem is alert always prints NaN.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>HTML 5 Boilerplate</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/style.css">
    <script>
        const PI = 3.14159;

        function getAreaOfCircle(rad) {
            let area = PI * Math.pow(rad, 2);
            alert(area);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Type something..." id="myInput">
    <input type="button" onclick="getAreaOfCircle();" value="Calculate Area of a Circle">
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to pass input value on your function. As you're code to pass it on your function as argument/parameter. So you can code it like that:

```
<input type="button" onclick="getAreaOfCircle(document.getElementById('myInput').value);" value="Calculate Area of a Circle">
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the actual input text and convert its value into a floating number:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>HTML 5 Boilerplate</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/style.css">
    <script>
        const PI = 3.14159;

        function getAreaOfCircle() {
            //Get the radius from the input field 
            let rad = document.getElementById("myInput").value;
            //Check if the input is not empty, if it is set rad to 0
            rad = rad !== "" ? parseFloat(rad) : 0;
            let area = PI * Math.pow(rad, 2);
            alert(area.toFixed(2));
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter the circle radius" id="myInput">
    <input type="button" onclick="getAreaOfCircle();" value="Calculate Area of a Circle">
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not passing `rad` in the function `getAreaOfCircle`

So you can get value inside the function `getAreaOfCircle` as:

```
const rad = document.querySelector("#myInput").value;
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>HTML 5 Boilerplate</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/style.css">
    <script>
        const PI = 3.14159;

        function getAreaOfCircle() {
            const rad = document.querySelector("#myInput").value;
            let area = PI * Math.pow(rad, 2);
            alert(area);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Type something..." id="myInput">
    <input type="button" onclick="getAreaOfCircle();" value="Calculate Area of a Circle">
</body>
</html>
```